# Auto Layout Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I am trying to create entire iOS application without using Interface Builder at all. I am facing some problems with auto layout.

My AppDelegate.m file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

And my MainViewController.m file

```
@interface MainViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label;
@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *superview = self.view;

    // Configuring view

    NSLog(@"Constraints: %@", self.view.constraints);
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Configuring label

    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    self.label.text = @"text";
    [self.label sizeToFit];
    self.label.frame = CGRectMake(8, 20, self.label.frame.size.width, self.label.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:self.label];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self.label addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:10.0]];
}
```

This code gives me this exception message:

> 2015-08-11 22:12:53.940 AutoLayoutWithoutInterfaceBuilder[5088:130112]
>   The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint:
>   
>   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7d53f190 )>  When added to a view, the
>   constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view
>   itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before
>   the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on
>   -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug. 2015-08-11 22:12:53.941 AutoLayoutWithoutInterfaceBuilder[5088:130112] View
>   hierarchy unprepared for constraint.  Constraint:
>   
>   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7d53f190 )>  Container hierarchy:  >
>     View not found in container hierarchy: >  That
>   view's superview: NO SUPERVIEW 2015-08-11 22:12:53.944
>   AutoLayoutWithoutInterfaceBuilder[5088:130112] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install
>   constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from
>   outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal.
>   constraint:
>   view:>'

When I created a single page application with IB, in viewDidLoad I have printed constraints of self.view.

```
NSLog(@"Main view constraints: %@", self.view.constraints);
```

It can be noticed that the view contains 4 constraints, while in Interface Builder they are not listed.

How can I setup Auto Layout in my application purely with code? I don't want to use Interface Builder at all, but I am pretty confused. Are there good guides about Auto Layout entirely by code?

Which constraints I have to add in code after initializing ViewController? What setup do I have to perform to make autolayout work properly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the constraint to `self.view`, not `self.label`. Both items in the constraint have to be descendants of the view you are adding your constraint to.